# How to determine if $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}e^{(\pi*n*i)/2}*\frac{1}{n^2}$ is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am having trouble with determining if

$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}e^{(\pi*n*i)/2}*\frac{1}{n^2}$

is convergent. 
I don't know what will happen with $e^{(\pi*n*I)/2}$ when n approaches infinity.
I am hoping someone can help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: By $I$, did you mean a square root of $-1$? That would usually be lower case.

Comment: I've edited that now but my understanding is you can write it both ways. Maple's default is upper case for example.

Comment: And in contrary to $\zeta(2)$ there is no closed-form for $\beta(2)$ where $ \beta(s)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n (2n+1)^{-s}$ because it is a Dirichlet L-function with odd character (instead there is one for $\beta(1)$)

Comment: I'm going to give you the benefit of the doubt and assume that when you say you don't know "what will happen with $e^{n\pi i/2}$", you mean that you would know how to decide convergence of the series if that factor were removed.  However it would *improve* your Question to state explicitly what you know about the series without those factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mid e^{\pi ni/2}\mid=1$, so by the comparison test with $\sum_n\dfrac1{n^2}$, it converges absolutely.

Comment: Interesting is the value of the given sum.